# Should the resume's PDF highlight links?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

[image]

This is a part of my resume generated using the `Careers.SO` website. The PDF generated is just great except that it does not highlight the links in a way that makes their presence known. The `certificate here` is actually a link to my sharable Coursera certificate but since its color is the same as the rest of the text around it, it makes it less intutive that a hyperlink exists.

Shouldn't changes be made so that the presence of links is known easily? For example, by underlining the text for the string?

Comment: *find* the certificate here. I should be a little more careful xD

Comment: You should also be `careful` not to `abuse` inline code formatting for `things that aren't code`.

Comment: Using more descriptive link text would already be a start; never name a link 'here'. *You can access the certificate on the __Coursera website__* would be a better link text.

Comment: @CodyGray Hey! Thanks for the positive criticism. What do you suggest? Making the text Italicized? :)